# n-Party Public Key Cryptography

Tags: c#, security, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

While 2-party public key cryptography is very well laid out in .net framework going n-party concerns me a lot. For instance securing a two-party video-conf. communication is quite easy:

1) Each party generate session specific RSA key pairs and get their public-keys signed by a trusted authority (i.e. a trusted server).
2) Eachy party exchange keys using `ECDiffieHellmanCng` thus the connection is now both authentic and secure (thinking that they use Vista/W7).

Now adding a 3rd participant to this communication will not work because key exchange algorithms are designed to derive a shared secret from 2 public keys only (especially using .NET and BouncyCastle). So the question is, how would you go about implementing a n-party public key cryptography schema which is still authentic (i.e. resistant to man in the middle attack) and secure (i.e. secure from eavesdropping).

**Edit**: Currently the ideas are as below, I'll go ahead and implement the most popular one as a part of the [NBusy.Communicator](http://www.nbusy.com/) library:

- Use a two-party communication scheme where one party acts as a federation server.
- Initiate a two-party communication and let one party to authenticate third-parties and share the secret/symmetric key.
- Use Multi-Party Key Agreement Scheme.

**Edit2**: I'm going with the "n-Party Diffie Hellman" algorithm, similar to the one described here but with some modifications: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diffy_helman.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that a "Multi-Party Key Agreement Scheme" is also possible but currently there doesn't seem to much practical implementations using .net/c#. Very neat academic (but very hard to implement) idea here from Giuseppe Atenies (IEEE): [Authenticated Multi-Party Key Agreement](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.2268).

I've also came across a very neat article at CodeProject about 3-tier Diffie Hellman which can possibly be extended to n-party, as in my case: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diffy_helman.aspx

Answer (score 4):

(Just thinking out loud)

You don't need a (complete) mesh of secure relations.

The point of the PK+Certificate is to distribute a symmetric key.

Any new participant only needs to establish identities with 1 existing node and can then get a copy of that symm key.

Comment: Nice idea but one of the main goals of key-agreement protocols is to never distribute the shared secret (i.e. the symmetric key) in any form, encrypted or not, but to derived at the client side. I'm sure there is a security concern behind this..

Comment: I've just noticed that what you are suggesting is some sort of decentralized version of [KDC](http://books.google.com/books?id=HsawoKBLZOwC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=distributing+the+shared+secret&source=bl&ots=qwiOzHgzEY&sig=f0bQ4eluxdR6hkMD5uBW99ICG0Y&hl=en&ei=XZilTZ6kI9HBswa59fmVCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) (key distribution center) logic. This may be a good idea actually.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason it has not been implemented yet, is because there is no need for it. Most security schemes work on a point to point basis where there are two parties. If there are more than 2 parties it is usually implemented as 2 two-party communication where one party works as a **Federation**.

Comment: Well actually multi-party key agreement schemes exist but there seems to be very little practical info on that. On the other hand using a "federation server" seems feasible too.

Comment: Can you please point me to some references, I am curious really if it exists... maybe only in military, etc.

Comment: Well there are papers on it but mostly very academic: [Authenticated Multi-Party Key Agreement](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=8FC0452ED86A48988D8B759EC728A56B?doi=10.1.1.50.2268&rep=rep1&type=ps) and also [An Efficient and Secure Protocol for Multi-party Key Establishment](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/44/5/463.full.pdf)

Comment: You're welcome. And also this [Authenticated Multi-Party Key Agreement](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.2268) but what I need is more practical ideas from .NET/C# minded people:) not academicians where they come up with mathematically possible but extremely hard to implement ideas.

Comment: My +1 to your question stays. I do not delete the answer so it stays there but I know I have not answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I'm just looking into other people's minds (and also testing stackoverflow community's ability to come up with answers to cryptic questions:)